# JdbcRepositoryFactory does not support Querydsl

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

Is the support for Querydsl remove in Spring Data Jdbc 3.0.0-M6? I am now getting an error ‘JdbcRepositoryFactory does not support Quersdsl’ after i upgraded from Spring Boot 3.0.0-M4 to 3.0.0-M5.

Comment: Could you show how you used QueryDsl with Spring Data JDBC?

Comment: …
import com.infobip.spring.data.jdbc.QuerydslJdbcRepository
….
public interface BookRepository extends QuerydslJdbcRepository<Book,String> {
}
…

Comment: Spring Data JDBC never supported Querydsl. You are using Infobip Spring Data Querydsl (https://github.com/infobip/infobip-spring-data-querydsl), which judging from your question might be incompatible with the latest milestones of Spring Data JDBC. I'd recommend opening a ticket with them.